# How to find out justification of paragraph using perl?

Tags: perl, ms-word, ole

Is there a method to find out the justification of a paragraph in a MS Word document. Can any one help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using OLE, it looks like you can get the justification (or alignment) via the `ParagraphFormat2` object, which has an `Alignment` property.  Here's an example from the OLE docs:

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(2).TextFrame2.TextRange2.ParagraphFormat2.Alignment
```

You can read more about this object [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff870379%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

To provide a Perl example of this, take a look at this example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Win32::OLE qw(in with);
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Word';
use Win32::OLE::Variant;

my $word = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Word.Application')
  || Win32::OLE->new( 'Word.Application', 'Quit' );
$word->{Visible} = 1;
my $doc = $word->{Documents}->Open('<full path to file>');
print $doc->Paragraphs(1)->{Alignment} . "\n";
$doc->Close();
```

You'll need to install the `Win32::OLE` library on a machine with Microsoft Word installed on it, at minimum.  When writing Perl applications to use OLE, anything that is an OLE object is a method call and anything that is a OLE member is a hash reference.

When you go to open the file, you'll need to provide the full path to the file, i.e. 'C:\\folder\\doc.docx'.  Change the number passed to `Paragraphs` for whichever paragraph you want (in OLE arrays start at 1.)

The `Alignment` key will return an int, which correspondes to a [`WdParagraphAlignment Enumeration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdparagraphalignment%28v=office.11%29.aspx).  I was able to test this out; 0 => Left, 1 => Center, 2 => Right, 3 => Justified.

Comment: Can explain me about how to use it in perl?

Comment: @Praveenkumar I've added an example to the post, please feel free to take a look.

Comment: After executing, it throws 'Can't call method "Open" on an undefined value at para2.pl line 18'.

Comment: Throwing @ the second last line (my $doc = ..).

Comment: @Praveenkumar Take a look at the updates that I just made.  You'll need to pass in the full path to the file when opening it.

Comment: :-  Thanks a lot, it is working. The only thing I need to do is to put '$doc->Paragraphs(1)->{Alignment} . "\n";' in for loop.  I got it.